# JodaTime Persisting DateTime as multi column

Tags: hibernate, grails, jodatime

So here's what I'm trying to do. I have a gsp view with a form that's posting the following with some example values:

params.startTime: 01:00:00 AM, params.startDate: 2013-01-01, params.timeZone: US/Central

Here's some code from my domain class

```
    class MyClass {
     DateTime startDate
    }
    static mapping {
     startDate type: PersistentDateTimeWithZone, {
      column name: "start_date_time"
      column name: "start_date_zone"
    }
```

And here's some code from my controller

```
    //This is a service i created to return the UTC id of a long time zone
    def tzs = new TimeZoneService()
    params.timeZone = tzs.getTimeZoneId(params.timeZone)    
    def startTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID(params.timeZone)

    def startDate = new DateTime(params.startDate + "T" + params.startTime, startTimeZone)
```

This is what this looks like in my database:

```
    start_date_time: 2013-01-01 01:00:00 
    start_date_zone: -06:00
```

So here's the problem. When I format startTime with the following pattern

```
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM dd, yyyy  h:mm a z");
```

My time zone comes up as -06:00 and not US/Central. Here are my questions: I'm trying out different approaches to persisting my DateTime. If i want to just use one column to persist date time and zone together how would I do that? If my properties for date-time-zone comes in as separate params, what's the right way to build a DateTime with those three params? Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this error, you need to get the UTC value for the time zone offset.  I believe the output that it gives you through Joda DateTimeZone is America/Chicago, America/Eastern, America/Pacific, etc. though, so if you want to have a custom value such as US/Central, you'll have to create a map for whatever values you want to match those offsets.

Hope this helps!